# Why do the images loaded by the wms tiles loaded by the osmdroid overlap?

Tags: osmdroid, wms

Requirement: I use the program provided by osmdroid to load the WMS, and the basic graphs can be loaded successfully. However, some graphs will have many overlapping graphs when they are translated or zoomed. I can't find the cause? The following is a graph that is loaded normally and I have problems overlapping?
The following link is loaded by me, but the boundary is the longitude and latitude boundary converted rom the number of tiles

[normal picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQnxq.png)  ;   [overlap picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AuoNS.jpg)

http://www.ign.es/wms-inspire/pnoa-ma?SERVICE=WMS&request=GetMap&width=256&height=256&version=1.1.1&layers=OI.MosaicElement&bbox=-714227.5924785882,5175704.060564015,-709335.6226670891,5180596.030375512&srs=EPSG:3857&format=image/png&transparent=true&styles=OI.MosaicElement.Default

I hope someone can help me analyze the problem?

Comment: Tested with basic WMS command ***GetCapabilities*** with URL http://www.ign.es/wms-inspire/pnoa-ma?SERVICE=WMS&request=GetCapabilities&version=1.1.1 but OsmDroid sample WMS Source demo returns a few log outputs `"success, however the mime type does not appear to be an image application/vnd.ogc.se_xml; charset=UTF-8"` https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wms/reference.html

Comment: When using the URL in your post, OsmDroid sample WMS Source demo from OsmDroid demo app (available on Google Play Store) returns the following EMS exception string `"There was an error communicating with the server: Unexpected token (position: TEXT PNG..."`

Comment: You can test the WMS link with ***More Samples > Tilesources > WMS Source*** demo from OsmDroid demo app from https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.osmdroid. Take note the demo app works well on Android 9 and below since for Android 10+ devices, the following error occurs: `"There was an error communicating with the server: Cleartext HTTP traffic to www.igns.es not permitted"`

Comment: Please keep in mind that OsmDroid WMS support is still in beta. `"WMS support is BETA. Please report any issues"`

Comment: Please use this link to report an OsmDroid problem with a sample code snippet that you have tried.  https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/issues

Comment: https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/wiki/WMS-Support

Comment: Thank you very much, ecle. Your answer is as follows

GetCapabilities read that there are the following three layers, but only FONDO is loaded normally here, and the other two have overlapping effects

OI.MosaicElement

OI.OrthoimageCoverage

fondo

Comment: GetMap: http://www.ign.es/wms-inspire/pnoa-ma?SERVICE=WMS&request=GetMap&width=256&height=256&version=1.1.1&layers=OI.MosaicElement&bbox= -356320.7620706335,5010160.566513233,-356311.20744209364,5010170.121141771&srs=EPSG:3857&format=image/png&transparent=true&styles=OI.MosaicElement.Default

I used EPSG: 3857 to load

The following three figures correspond to the three layers I loaded

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3Qwx.jpg

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y39xp.jpg

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yIBMn.jpg